# Starting newer Karaf (4.2.8) on linux, feature:repo-add camel does not work

Tags: installation, apache-karaf

maybe somebody can help me.
I, was testing  karaf in my local windows laptop  an everything work fine. But now  I'm trying to install it  on  Centos Linux  server, but Im not getting the same results.

My steps:
1-Donwload Karaf from http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/karaf/4.2.8/apache-karaf-4.2.8.tar.gz
2- Unzipped  in the centos linux  path: /usr/local/apache-karaf-4.2.8
3- Check the java version installed in the server
                           JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_251 
                           PATH=.../usr/local/jdk1.8.0_251/jre/bin..
4- run sudo ./bin/karaf  and then

**karaf: JAVA_HOME not set; results may vary**
        __ __                  ____
       / //_/____ __________ _/ __/
      / ,<  / __ `/ ___/ __`/ /_
     / /| |/ /*/ / /  / /*/ / __/
    /*/ |*|__,*/*/   __,*/*/

Apache Karaf (4.2.8)

Anyway  the  shell   become active, but  I tried to add features  and I receved this error ( It doesn't seem to be related to the previous message)

karaf@root()> feature:repo-add camel
Adding feature url mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/RELEASE/xml/features
Error executing command: Error resolving artifact org.apache.camel.karaf:apache-camel:xml:features:RELEASE: [Failed to resolve version for org.apache.camel.karaf:apache-camel:xml:features:RELEASE: Could not find metadata org.apache.camel.karaf:apache-camel/maven-metadata.xml in local (/root/.m2/repository)] : mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/RELEASE/xml/features

I did the same on my PC and everything worked perfectly.  Im missing  something  specific for Linux ?   Any Idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Karaf uses `etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg` to list all the m2 repos from where he can downloads your bundles/features.

By default, the value for this distribution is :

```
org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories= \
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2@id=central, \
    https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group@id=apache@snapshots@noreleases, \
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ops4j-snapshots@id=ops4j.sonatype.snapshots.deploy@snapshots@noreleases
```

However, in your case, it seems it tries to get it from `/root/.m2/repository`. Could you check your `etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg` and see if there is no modification to it ?